# Top 10 filter Pareto with Date Slice

Tags: powerbi, dax

good afternoon.

I made a pareto chart in the top 10 states, but when I apply a filter to the data slice the measure of "cumulative goals" falls apart.

correct:[image]

Wrong:[image]

For the measures used:

```
Goals =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'All domains - main data'[Value] );
    FILTER (
        'All domains - main data';
        'All domains - main data'[Attribute] <> "Goal Completions"
    )
)

Classification =
RANKX ( ALL ( 'All domains - main data'[Region] ); [Objectives];; DESC )

Cumulative goals =
CALCULATE (
    [Goals];
    TOPN (
        [Classification];
        ALL ( 'All domains - main data'[Region] );
        [Goals]; DESC
    )
)


Total =
CALCULATE (
    [Goals];
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'All domains - main data'; 'All domains - main data' )
)

% Pareto = [Cumulative targets] / [Total]
```

Comment: Why is it wrong? What values are you expecting?

Comment: @AlexisOlson the "goals acumulative' dont acumulate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this will work, but try this for `Cumulative goals`.

```
Cumulative goals =
SUMX (
    TOPN (
        [Classification];
        ALL ( 'All domains - main data'[Region] );
        [Goals]; DESC
    );
    [Goals]
)
```

Using `TOPN` as a filter table inside `CALCULATE` is a bit odd.